# AngularJS Ctrl As Syntax with Services

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angularjs-controlleras

I'm migrating my Angular 1.x code to use the newer, more preferred syntax of avoiding using $scope and using the controller as syntax. I'm having an issue with getting data from a service though.

Here's my example:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$location', 'userService',
  function($http, $location, userService) {

    this.name = 'John Doe';

    // this.userData = {

    // }

    this.userData = userService.async().then(function(d) {
      return d;
    });


    console.log(this.userData);


  }
]);

myApp.service('userService', function($http) {

  var userService = {
    async: function() {
      // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
      var promise = $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(function(response) {
        // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
        // console.log(response);
        // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
        return response.data;
      });
      // Return the promise to the controller
      return promise;
    }
  };
  return userService;

});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div id="ctrl-as-exmpl" ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainctrl">

    <h1>Phone Numbers for {{mainctrl.name}}</h1>

    <button ng-click="">newest</button>
    <p>{{mainctrl.userData}}</p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="users in mainctrl.userData">{{users.phone}} -- {{users.email}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

This issue I'm having is that the data returned from the userService.async is an object that I can't seem to drill down thru to get the data from, as the data is a child of $$state, which can't seem to be used in the view.

If this isn't the proper way to use services in the Controller As/$scope-less syntax, what is the proper way?

Live example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ejHReaAIvVzlSExL5Elw?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missed an important part of promises - when you return a value from a promise, you return a new promise that will resolve to this value.

The current way to set the data returned from a promise to a local variable in your controller is this:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$location', 'userService',
  function($http, $location, userService) {

    this.name = 'John Doe';

    userService.async().then(function(d) {
      this.userData = d;
    });
  }
]);
```

But now you are in a catch because of the scope of `this`, so it is common to use a "placeholder" variable for the controller `this` scope.

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$location', 'userService',
  function($http, $location, userService) {

    var $ctrl = this; // Use $ctrl instead of this when you want to address the controller instance

    $ctrl.name = 'John Doe';

    userService.async().then(function(d) {
      $ctrl.userData = d;
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: If I log out both 'this' and the placeholder value (in my plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/KBnz7yQkyBp3B8MPFpYd?p=preview I am using 'vm'), they both have the returned data from the userService $http call. However, only using the placeholder works for getting the data to render in the view. Why is that?

Comment: Because of JS scope, when you are inside the anonymous function in the `then`, the `this` keyword address the anonymous function, that is why you need to set the `this` of the controller function instance to a variable, so that instance will be available in all the "sub" functions inside the controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.userData = userService.async().then(function(d) {
  return d;
});
```

In this bit of code `this.userData` is actually being defined as a promise.  If you want the data that is being returned, you need to use the `d` parameter from your `.then` `function` like so:

```
userService.async().then(function(d){
    this.userData = d;
    //a console.log() here would determine if you are getting the data you want.  
});
```

**Edit**
I just noticed in your Service that you are already using `.data` on your response object.

Honestly, my best advice to you would be to just return the promise from the `http.get()` call inside of your service like this:

```
myApp.service('userService', function($http) {
    var userService = {
        async: function() {
          return $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
        }
    };
    return userService;

});
```

And then you could use something like this to capture and utilize the response data:

```
userService.async().then(function(response){
    this.userData = response.data;
);
```

This may be a bit cleaner of a solution

Comment: Ok, that is how I had the code structured originally, but with it setup that way, this.userData comes back as undefined when it's logged. Example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ejHReaAIvVzlSExL5Elw?p=preview

Comment: I just updated my answer with a different structure that might help you out

Comment: I just looked at your plunker as well.  `this.userData` will never be defined where you `console.log()` it out.  This is because when that `console.log` runs it is still waiting on the response from the webserver.  `this.userData` is defined if you add in `console.log(this.userData)` inside your `.then` `function` after it is set to d

Comment: Ok, in Edward's example, this.userData logs out the array correctly, but when trying to use it in the view, nothing is shown.

Comment: @SerpicoLugNut we can't do all the work for you, try fix it first